# How many times an app has been started

Tags: java, netbeans

Good day all!

I've been working on a java application in Netbeans for some time. The place where I work at has been using the application to check our inventory inside the Warehouse. Now we got to a point where I would like to get compensated for the application. However, because this started as a hobby I haven't registered the hours spent on developing the application. I would like to know if there's a way to check how many times Netbeans has been started, and how long it has been running for a given period of time (say, the last few months).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just modify your software to keep a count of the number of times run. Get the company to agree to let you bill them for usage going forward. Request remuneration for work done so far.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll be having a meeting this week to discuss further details and such. So i'm guessing there's no way to actually look back and see how much or how often Netbeans has run?

Comment: Only if you had auditctl installed previously.